# Home ADSL Modem Dropping Packets?

Tags: router, packet-loss, adsl

I know this is supposed to be a "pro" forum, but I'm hoping someone can help since my ISP isn't doing much to try and fix things.

My ISP has given me a DSL modem / Router combo - a ADB / Pirelli P.DG A2100N and I have a 4096 / 767 kbps connection.  I use it purely as modem and router, and have the wireless AP feature turned off.  I run it to a Ubiquiti Networks Toughswitch and use a Ubiquiti UAP as the wireless access point - although I've ran tests directly wired to the router with nothing else connected, and still see the same issues.

I've been having issues where latency suddenly spikes from 8ms to google.com to 250+ if someone does *anything* on the internet.  If I run a speedtest or something, I can see latencies above 3000ms.  Regularly when downloading something, even if the speed is throttled to , it can get random drops to 0kbps every few seconds.

Online gaming is impossible because I notice the sudden lag-outs in the connection, and video streams or VoIP drop out as well - it's not at all consistent.

I managed to find the password to my modem and I don't think I see anything wrong with the settings - but I looked for the logs and found this:

```
Jun 6 17:10:30  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:10:30  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:10:31  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:10:40  user    warn    kernel: __ratelimit: 63 callbacks suppressed  
Jun 6 17:10:40  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:10:40  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:10:40  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:10:40  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:10:40  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:10:40  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:11:22  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:11:23  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:11:24  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:11:24  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:11:24  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:11:24  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:11:24  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:11:25  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:11:25  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:11:25  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:11:29  user    warn    kernel: __ratelimit: 15 callbacks suppressed  
Jun 6 17:11:29  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:11:29  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:11:30  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.  
Jun 6 17:11:30  user    warn    kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet.
Jun 6 17:55:26  user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmcfg: OAM loopback response not received on VCC 1.1.3
Jun 6 17:55:27  user    warn    kernel: bcmxtmcfg: OAM loopback response not received on VCC 1.1.4
```

So, as I understand it, it appears the router is dropping packets?

If that's the case, is there anything in the config that I can change?  Or should I buy a new router, a new modem, or both?

Comment: maybe you can ssh or telnet in, (run nmap on it nmap -p22,23 192.168.0.1) and see.. If you can and get the user/pass to get in, then you could try the iptables command, and some command there might be able to change the size of the connection tracking table. There is module in iptables called conntrack, but no table called that AFAIK, though I don't know much about iptables. Maybe you can download http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/manual.html#what  and that will help,  but i'm no expert!

Comment: Are those messages related to network traffic you were generating at the time?  If so, what kind of traffic was it?  What can you do to make new messages appear in the logfile?  The more specific the activity that generates them, the more informative the messages become.

Answer (score 0):

conntrack full = TCP connection tracking table is full

That's the table used to track simultaneous TCP connections between any local host talking to remote hosts so that the return goes to the right local host (ie: natting table)

That can happens if the router is configured with a low number.

Usual Suspects:

- Bittorrent
- DOS (someone trying to connect to you while you have a DMZ/port forwarding enabled)
- infected with Virus/Zombiefied Bot

From the syslog you've shown, the router seems to be running a linux flavor.  You might or might not be able to configure a higher number in the router, but at first I'd look at the source of the connections and limit those (ie: say, your significant other and child are both torrenting at the same time...)